# onRequestPermissionsResult() not called in fragment, tried all solutions I could find

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

onRequestPermissionsResult() is never called when I run my code. I'm have a method in my fragment that requests permissions:

```
void initiateGalleryUpload() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setMessage(getString(R.string.read_storage_permission_rationale))
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                                Timber.d("Requesting permissions for read external storage");
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);
                }
            } else {
                controller.startGalleryPick();
            }
        }
        else {
            controller.startGalleryPick();
        }
```

And another method in the same fragment that overrides onRequestPermissionsResult:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Timber.d("onRequestPermissionsResult: req code = " + " perm = " + permissions + " grant =" + grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        // 1 = "Read external storage" allowed when gallery selected
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Timber.d("Call controller.startGalleryPick()");
                controller.startGalleryPick();
            }
        }
        break;
```

Common mistakes I have read up on but that don't apply to my case:

- Not using the appcompatv4 requestPermissions - I am using that
- Not overriding onRequestPermissionsResult in the same fragment - I am doing so in the same fragment
- Not updating support library - we are running the latest version

The permissions dialog appears as expected, and I can select "OK".

Would greatly appreciate some help with this as I have gone through a dozen StackOverflow posts to no avail. Complete code [here](https://github.com/misaochan/apps-android-commons/blob/fix-permissions/app/src/main/java/fr/free/nrw/commons/nearby/NearbyMapFragment.java) if anyone needs it.

Comment: Is the permission dialog itself appearing?

Comment: Yes, the permissions dialog is appearing. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Try overriding `onRequestPermissionResult()` in the hosting activity, and see if that one gets called. If it does, then we need to figure out why that's not getting routed to the fragment.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It is indeed called in the activity, and there was actually another onRequestPermissionsResult() in the activity, which might explain why it happened to begin with. If the activity already overrides that method, can the fragment not do so?

Comment: Make sure that you chain to the superclass implementation for any permissions that aren't being handled at the activity level. That may allow the fragment to get a shot.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you meant by that - could you clarify please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your activity-level `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, handle any permission requests issued by the activity.

If the `requestCode` does not match one requested by the activity (e.g., in a `default` branch for a `switch`), chain to the superclass (`super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);`). If you are not doing this, that might prevent `FragmentActivity` from routing results to a fragment, for fragment-initiated requests.